# Display content of all currently detached screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a few detached screens running. Now I’d like to see their current state for each of them. Currenlty, I do

```
$ screen -r
# look at the cryptic numbers
$ screen -r <paste number one>
# look at output
<Ctrl-A> D
$ screen -r
# look at the cryptic numbers to find the next one
$ screen -r <paste number two>
# look at output
<Ctrl-A> D
$ screen -r
# look at the cryptic numbers to find the next one
# and so on
$ screen -r <paste number three>
# look at output
```

Is there a single command that lets me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think time shows that the answer to this question is simply: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want the equivalent of the `hardcopy` command?  You can use the `-X` option.

```
 $ screen -p 9 -X hardcopy
 $ file hardcopy.9
 hardcopy.9: ASCII text
```

You would then cycle through each window.  Unfortunately, you can't get a list of windows without using something like `expect` since the output is emitted to `screen`'s display, not stdout.  But for a command like `hardcopy`, if there is no window, no file is generated.

If you know you want this beforehand, you can `log` each when the window is created (`screen -L longrunningprogram` internal command).  Then you could see the output outside of screen.  You could also turn this on after the program starts inside `screen` or using the `-X` option above.

Edit (from Stephene's comment):

```
$ screen -X hardcopydir /tmp; screen -X at \# hardcopy
$ ls /tmp/hardcopy.*
hardcopy.0  hardcopy.2  hardcopy.4  hardcopy.6  hardcopy.8
hardcopy.1  hardcopy.3  hardcopy.5  hardcopy.7
```

Comment: I guess hardcopy could be part of the solution, but of course that would only be usable inside a script that finds out all running screens, allocates a temporary file name, calls hardcopy on each of them, prints it to the user and removes the temporary file. Which would be possible, but does not qualify as a single command :-)

Comment: You can use `at \# hardcopy` to run `hardcopy` on every windows. See also `harcopydir` to specify where hardcopies are to be dumped.

Comment: Good addition, Stehpane.  I always forget about `at`; I usually only use it in conjunction with `grep` to find something in a stream.  Works well.

Comment: Joachin; for a single command without `at`, it would just be a shell for loop: `for i in $(seq 20); do screen -p $i -X hardcopy; done`; this would be a "Compound Command" which is still a single command (unless you are talking about a single "Simple Command").